# django error using pagination and raw queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, pagination

when I try to add pagination to my page it gives me error `object of type 'RawQuerySet' has no len()`
views:

```
class StudentmessageListView(ListView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'
    template_name = 'student_messagesall.html'
    context_object_name = 'messages_all'
    model = Message
    paginate_by = 3

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Message.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM ertaapp_message where to_prof_id=%s ORDER BY create_date DESC',[self.request.user.id])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(StudentmessageListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['reps'] = ReplyMessage.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM ertaapp_replymessage')
        return context
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `raw` here?

Comment: I have used raw queryset in all of my views because I'm more familiar with sql.
now there are too many raw querysets that I must change to filter

Comment: Most of those built in views are designed to use normal querysets, since these queries look really simple not using them would be a mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should return the list instead of raw queryset.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return list(Message.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM ertaapp_message where to_prof_id=%s ORDER BY create_date DESC',[self.request.user.id]))
```